# string de respuesta se corta en 2033 caracteres cuando es XML

Tags: c#, asp, iis

hice un sitio web con c# MVC que contiene una función ajax que regresa un xml, cuando lo ejecuto en visual studio todo bien, pero cuando lo pongo en el iis el xml se corta en 2033 caracteres.

Ya puse esto en el web.config y no  funciona

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="500000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
</security>

<system.web>
   <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="500000000"  executionTimeout="120" />
</system.web>
```

Y en el IIS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás seguro de que el problema es el IIS? Creo recordar que había algun bug con SqlServer en consultas que devuelven xml y que truncaba la respuesta a 2033 caracteres. Lo que estás devolviendo es el resultado de una consulta `FOR XML` a SqlServer ?

Comment: Si @Pikoh es un FOR XML, lo corro en el SQL Server Management y si me sale completo

Comment: Lo imaginaba. El problema es en el conector de .net con sqlserver. Si estas usando `ExecuteReader`, prueba a usar `ExecuteXmlReader` en su lugar

Comment: Estoy usando string XML = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());, pero deja lo cambio a ExecuteXmlReader y te aviso, muchas gracias.

Comment: Bueno ya lo probé y ya quedo eres un genio muchas gracias @Pikoh me salvaste de que me dieran cuello jaja

Comment: De nada. Voy a añadir una respuesta ya que es algo que le puede pasar a alguien mas en el futuro y puede llegar a volverte loco :)

Answer (score 2):

El problema proviene de la forma en la que el conector .NET se comunica con el SqlServer.

Al parecer, por algún tema de la implementación interna de este, las respuestas en XML se truncan a 2033 caracteres. Lo que se hace en estos casos, es que el resultado se devuelve en varias filas de 2033 caracteres como máximo.

Hay varias soluciones. La más sencilla es usar `ExecuteXmlReader` en lugar de `ExecuteReader` o `ExecuteScalar`.

Otra opción, dado que la respuesta viene en varias filas, sería concatenarlas todas para obtener el xml completo, algo similar a esto:

```
string xml = "";
while (reader.Read())
{
    xml = xml + reader.GetString(0);
}
```

No se si en versiones más modernas del conector .net está resuelto este problema, ya que la única referencia que he encontrado está eliminada del servidor de Microsoft, pongo aquí el enlace usando [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150311184409/http://support.microsoft.com:80/kb/310378)